# Why do I get no output at my VHDL multiplier?

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I am trying to make a 4 bit multiplier. Here is my top level design:
[image]

And here are the two modules:
[image]
[image]

However when I try to simulate this I get no output. My testbench:

```
    ARCHITECTURE behavior OF sim3 IS 

    -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

    COMPONENT multiplicator
    PORT(
         a : IN  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
         b : IN  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
         reset : IN  std_logic;
         clk : IN  std_logic;
         start : IN  std_logic;
         prod : OUT  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
         ready : OUT  std_logic
        );
    END COMPONENT;


   --Inputs
   signal a : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal b : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal reset : std_logic := '0';
   signal clk : std_logic := '0';
   signal start : std_logic := '0';

    --Outputs
   signal prod : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
   signal ready : std_logic;

   -- Clock period definitions
   constant clk_period : time := 10 ns;

BEGIN

    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: multiplicator PORT MAP (
          a => a,
          b => b,
          reset => reset,
          clk => clk,
          start => start,
          prod => prod,
          ready => ready
        );

   -- Clock process definitions
   clk_process :process
   begin
        clk <= '0';
        wait for clk_period/2;
        clk <= '1';
        wait for clk_period/2;
   end process;


   -- Stimulus process
   stim_proc: process
   begin        
        wait for clk_period;
        reset<='1';
        wait for clk_period;
        reset<='0';
        a<="0011";
        b<="0010";
        start <='1';
        wait for clk_period*10;
   end process;

END;
```

When I am setting the start to '1' the simulation just stops. I don't know why. I get the folowing error:

```
ERROR: at 20 ns(10000): Iteration limit 10000 is reached. Possible zero delay oscillation detected where simulation can not advance in time because signals can not resolve to a stable value in File "D:/faculta/PL II/multiplicator/reg8.vhd" Line 45. Please correct this code in order to advance past the current simulation time.
```

[image]

I don't see what could be wrong at that line:

```
q_s <= "00000000" WHEN reset='1' ELSE d WHEN reset='0' and load='1' ELSE q_s;
```

Some help please?

Comment: The error is occurring inside your `reg8` entity. It would be useful to be able to see this code; the one line you posted is not sufficient for us to see where the loop is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a register with a load enable, use clock edge register. The iteration limit is a delta cycle limit in ISIM. Introducing a '1' in `b` you get a striking oscillator, a loop with delta cycle delays and inversion (the summing). Make num4, reg4 and reg8 clock edge driven with their loads as enables, this appears compatible with [Lab10](http://vega.unitbv.ro/~tulbure/vlsi/lab10.pdf)  which shows the use of a clock (and the VHDL source for @scary_jeff, albeit expressed in type BIT instead of std_logic). This feedback phenomenon is mentioned in William Kafig's book **VHDL 101 Everything you need to know to get started**,  in Chapter 4.

Google Translate helps.  No one ever seems to provide their handouts for their assignments.

If you look at the original implementation of assignment to `q_s` in `reg4`:

```
block1: 
    block (ck = '1' and not ck'stable)
    begin
        q_s <= guarded "0000" when reset = '1' else
                           d  when reset = '0' and load = '1' else
                         q_s;
    end block block1;
```

I'd translate this into a synthesizable process statement instead of a block statement, making in clear `reg4` (and `reg8`) is a clocked register:

```
block1: 
    process (ck)
    begin
        if rising_edge(ck) then 
            if reset = '1' then
                q_s <= (others => '0');
            elsif load = '1' then
                q_s <= d;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
```

The reason the original works is because a block statement can have a guard statement.

The change makes it clear the `q_s` is a clocked register with a synchronous reset.

You also might note we no longer reference `q_s` and can assign q directly.

In the control state machine the process assigning `next_state` to `current_state` can likewise be updated:

```
    process (ck)
    begin
        if ck'event and ck = '1' then  -- or rising_edge(ck)
            current_state <= next_state;
        end if;
    end process;
```

Simply for readability.  It's uncommon to use the form `not ck'stable` for signifying a clock event, noting you also appear to have missed the implication in implementing `reg8`, potentially in `reg4` and `automat` as well.

The synthesis eligibility of a guarded expression as an edge sensitive clock is demonstrated in IEEE Std 1076.6-2004, 
6.1.3.6 Edge-sensitive storage using a guarded block.

Comment: This is one case of a more general rule: **Asynchronous sequential logic should be avoided**.  Anyone expert enough to stand a chance at making it work also understands why it is so rarely appropriate.

Comment: @BenVoigt - Having looked at the problem in depth I'd imagine the issue comes from 'filling in the blanks' creating a `reg8` not shown in the lab assignment, a mater of not understanding the use of a guard statement to imply an edge sensitive register.  I successfully duplicated the assignment using std_logic;

Comment: Thank you David! I finally made it work and I have a good simulation now. The problem was that I didn't actually understood what the clock signals do. This is a very nice explanation and the clock is good now. It's working well.

Comment: I got it to work too, although I used a block statement instead of a separate caledate entity/architecture. Saw your symptom in num4 as well.  Had a transcription error. There only needs to be one reg8, prod can be fed from the accumulator.